# Can I use Parse and Firebase at the same time?

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, firebase, multiplayer

I like the simplicity of Parse to handle the user side of things as well as push notifications and all the other cool features, but I also want to use Firebase to make use of the real time database for the widely multiplayer game aspect of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use it. There are many apps available that are using time for real time. Check out this [link](https://github.com/relatedcode/RealtimeChat)

Comment: Hope there'll be a swift version soon lol. But thanks ! This gives me hope !!

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use them both. But if you wanna use this two at the same time at the one variable/data it can be a problem. Just use them with the separate data e.g=Firebase - realtime event handling, Parse - save/load score & notifications

Comment: That's actually exactly what I wanted to do. At the same time I don't want to use Firebase for users. Just the actual game part